# Basketball interesting odds.

Tags: probability

Not long ago I went on a betting site to see out of curiosity the odds of one team winning the match. I got an interesting statistic:

> The team has 72% chances of winning. But this team only wins in 60% of cases with such chances.

So I wondered, what would be the final odds for this team to win? Would I simply need to to multiply $0.72 \times 0.6$? Somehow I think it might a bit more complex than this, but I don't know how.

Oh and by the way, this team lost the game if you are curious.

Comment: As you can see from the posts below, people are reading your question in different ways.  Perhaps you could clarify?  The way I read it is "some odds maker has predicted that my team will win the upcoming match with probability $.72$.  Historically, however, the team underperforms predictions ...winning only about $60\%$ of the matches for which the prediction was $72\%$.  How should I estimate the probability of their winning the next match?"  Have I got it right?  If not (certainly likely enough), what is the right way to read your question?

Comment: @lulu I answered under your answer without noticing this comment. The way you interpreted was correct.

Comment: No problem.  I responded to your comment under my post below.

Comment: Probabilities and odds posted by betting establishments are usually fudged a bit (or a lot) so that the establishment can make a profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to your formula.  If the thing were decided by a coin toss (so the reported probability and the historical probability were both $.5$) then the answer is $.5$, not $.5\times .5$.

In general, it's hard to interpret disagreements between historical probabilities and future predictions.  Perhaps the people setting the $.72$ prediction know something that causes them to increase their estimate.  In any case, that conflict is not a math problem...not without more information on the numbers.

Comment: with 72% chance of winning you can say in theory that the probability of them not winning for three games is above 2%.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  Not following.  I read the question as asserting that $.72$ was a prediction for some particular upcoming match. Maybe I had that wrong, certainly some of the other writers seem to be assuming something else.  In any case, I don't see anything about three games (nor do we know anything about independence).

Comment: @lulu That's the way to interpret it. The $0.72$ was indeed a prediction for a particular upcoming math.

Comment: Ok!  So, in that case you are faced with a conflict between a future prediction and the historical record.  That isn't a math problem, as there can be external factors.  Perhaps the bookie knows that Lebron James is joining the team for the next match, and that therefore the historical record is an underestimate.  Keep in mind, that the bookie knows the historical record just like you do and is nonetheless  projecting a higher probability.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to decide what are the chances for the team to win?

Comment: That's not what I said, I just said that there is a conflict.  After all, you have access to more information than you have revealed.  You know what people are saying about the match and therefore you know why people are predicting chances greater than the historical record.  You have to decide for yourself whether you think people are interpreting the external factors appropriately.  It's a basketball problem, not a math problem.

Comment: Just to say:  the Efficient Market Hypothesis would say that the market probability is the best estimator.  After all, the market has all the information, including all the historical record.  I think, of course, that few people would sign on to such a simplistic view.

Comment: Just to say, this conflict arises all the time.  Some stock analysts say a stock will do one thing, some say another,  and of course you have the historical record.  Just as here, there is no objective mathematical way to establish the "truth".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first number is not really a probability. They have a model that compares two teams "scores" and then outputs a probability out of it. So you should interpret it as 
"This team wins 60% of the times when the computer outputs the score "72%"

So that would mean that the probability of the team winning is 60%

Clearly, these are not really probabities about the future, it's just a measure of what happened in the past.